# PHP adding two arrays to a parent array from single large array

Tags: php, arrays

I have a single array such as this:

```
array('one','two','three','four','five','six','seven')
```

I'm using a foreach to iterate through this and I'd like to build an array like this:

```
array(
    array('one'),
    array('two')
),
array(
    array('three'),
    array('four')
),
array(
    array('three'),
    array('five')
),
array(
    array('six'),
    array('seven')
)
```

Any suggestions on how do this?

Thanks!

Comment: What is the purpose of this? Why would you do this in the first place? Also your third array uses "three" a second time, so the pattern is broken.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [array_chunk](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php).
From the PHP Manual:

> **array array_chunk ( array $input , int $size [, bool $preserve_keys = false ] )**
>
> Chunks an array into size large chunks. The last chunk may
> contain less than size elements.

In your case you need `$output_array = array_chunk($input_array, 2);`

And then if you want to convert the leaves to arrays:

```
function leaves_to_array(&$item, $key)
{
    if (!is_array($item))
        $item = array($item);
}

array_walk_recursive($output_array, 'leaves_to_array');
```

Comment: Wow... here I was writing my own!

Comment: This works great, except it drops off the last item if it's an odd number of arrays.

Comment: No it doesn't. `The last chunk may contain less than size elements.`